# Angular Rest API call returning 401 Unauthorized

Tags: angular, rest, http-headers

My Angular project throwing error **`401 Unauthorized`** when I am calling Rest Api's

> "Http failure response for https://url/products/search: 401
>   Unauthorized"

This is my code

```js
this.httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders(
        { 
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          'org-code-rc' : 'VWiHL8RFR8fRGNjfZI=',
          'Authorization': `Basic` + btoa('myUsername:myPass'),
        }
    )
}
```

And getting result here

```js
public getProducts() {

    return this._http.get(this.baseUrl, {
        headers: this.httpOptions
    });
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Check whether request headers were set properly or not. And cross-check with your rest API side you are sending correct information or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're already setting the headers so you need to change your code too:

```
public getProducts() {
     return this._http.get(this.baseUrl, this.httpOptions);
}
```

Because otherwise you will have the headers in the headers params and it won't work

Answer (score 1):

For one, there's a space missing between `Basic` and the credentials:

```
  'Authorization': `Basic` + btoa('myUsername:myPass'),
```

Comment: We are accessing a AIrwatch API which accepts basic authentication. Which we verified in API tester tool  and we are getting the output

Comment: Yeah, I deleted my comment. See Sjoerd's answer above, the headers weren't passed correctly to the HttpClient.